# IE not rendering hidden Input fields for MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a hidden input field

```
<input id="mine" name="mine" type="hidden" value="1" />
```

For some Reason this never renders in IE (View Source) but I can see it fine in FIrefox and Chrome. I am using Jquery to serialize the form and again the hidden input isn't being passed in only IE.

Comment: Talking about "rendering" is a bit confusing since hidden fields aren't supposed to be rendered (=displayed on the screen). Had me thinking for a while...

Comment: Is this hidden input part of the initial HTML or is this hidden field part of some partial that is loaded subsequently using AJAX? In any cases you will have to show some code that would allow to reproduce the behavior that you are observing.

Comment: if input is part of code from server... have you validated page for broken tags, mismatched attribute quotes etc?  IE hates invalid html

Comment: Everybody hates invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what Happened, For some reason IE just kept a cache of the site. I deleted everything and now it works.

Comment: Brotip: There's an option in the developer tools (F12) to disable cache for a domain (or altogether)